# Оптимизация кода php+mysql

Tags: оптимизация, php, парсер, mysql

Здрасте!
Проблема вот в чем - хостинг пишет что потребляю много ресурсов!
На Cron повесил с десяток php скриптов заходящих в базу и обновляющих строки!
Вопрос вот в чем можно ли как то оптимизировать код либо заменить альтернативным, заранее спасибо!
Вот сам код:

```
<?php
    $dbhost='dbhost';
    $database='database';
    $dbuser='dbuser';
    $dbpswd='dbpswd';

    $dbh = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");
    mysql_select_db($database) or die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");

    function checkOnline($stream)
    {
    $ident = $stream['code'];
    $service = $stream['service'];
    $link = "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=".$ident;
    $json = file_get_contents($link);
    $exist = strpos($json, 'name');
    $json_file = @file_get_contents("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=".$ident, 0, null, null);
    $json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);
    $obs        = $json_array[0]['channel_count'];      
    if ($exist)
    {
        $query = "UPDATE streams_new SET state = 'ONLINE', obs = '$obs' WHERE id = '".$stream['id']."'";
        mysql_query($query); 
        echo ($stream['PLAYER']."ONLINE: $link | $obs <br>");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "UPDATE streams_new SET state = 'OFFLINE', obs = '0' WHERE id = '".$stream['id']."'";
        mysql_query($query);
        echo ($stream['player']."OFFLINE: $link<br>");      
    }       
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM streams_new WHERE (game = 'CSGO') ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while  ( ($stream = mysql_fetch_array($result))) 
        {
            checkOnline($stream);
        }
    mysql_close($dbh);
?>
```

З.Ы.: Так же прошу глянуть код, работающий с той-же базой - может его стоит подправить!

```
<?php
function generatePreviewPicture($ident, $service)
{
    $link = "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews/live_user_".$ident."-300x150.jpg";
    return $link;    
} 
function FullStreamLayout($stream, $counter)
{
    if ($stream['featured'] == 1)
    {
        $streamer = "<font color='#ed1b24'>".$stream['player']."</font>";   
    }
    else
    {
        $streamer = $stream['player']; 
    }   
    $service = $stream['service'];
    $game = $stream['game'];
    $image = generatePreviewPicture($stream['code'],$service);
    $sid = $stream['id'];
    $code = $stream['code']; 
    $obs = $stream['obs']; 
    $des = $stream['description'];

    $layout = " 
                <td style=\"padding: 5px 5px 15px 5px ;\">
                <div class=\"t3-module module black  masonry-brick\">   
                <div class=\"module-inner\">

                <div class=\"content-slidenews\">
                <a class=\"ja-title\" href='".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."?streamer=$code'><h3 style=\"color: #fff; font-family: 'novecento_wide_lightbold',sans-serif; font-size: 15px;\"><center>$streamer</center></span></h3></a>
                <a class=\"ja-title\" href='".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."?streamer=$code'>

                <img src=\"$image\" alt=\"\" ></a><br>
                <a class=\"readon\" href='".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."?streamer=$code'><center><h4 class=\"module-title \"><span>Смотреть стрим</span> </h4></center></a>
                </div></div></div></td>";

    echo ($layout);

} 
$dbhost='localhost';
$database='stream'; 
$dbuser='stream'; 
$dbpswd='stream';
$postto = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$ssilka = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpswd) OR DIE("Не могу создать соединение "); 
mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error()); 
if(isset($_GET['streamer']))
{
    $id = $_GET['streamer'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM streams_new where code = '$id'"; 
    $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
    $number = mysql_num_rows($res);

    if ($number == 0) 
    { 
      echo "<p>Стрмеров нет</p>"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
      while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) 
      { 
    $service = $row['service'];
    $ident = $row['code'];
    $name = $row['player'];
    $desc = $row['description'];

    $vk_id = $row['vk'];
    $steam_id = $row['steam'];
    $facebook_id = $row['facebook'];
    $twitter_id = $row['twitter'];
    $youtube_id = $row['youtube'];
    $reclama = "<p style=\"padding-top:100px;\"><center><p style=\"border: 1px solid #0B1216;\"><script async src=\"//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js\"></script>
<!-- dota2.gamestreamtv.ru - на странице стримеров -->
<ins class=\"adsbygoogle\"
     style=\"display:inline-block;width:468px;height:60px\"
     data-ad-client=\"ca-pub-9974938238086471\"
     data-ad-slot=\"2553155631\"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></p></center></p>";

    if (empty($vk_id)){
    echo  "";
    }
    else {
    $vk = "<li><a href=\"http://vk.com/$vk_id\"><i>1</i>Вконтакте</a></li>";

    }

        if (empty($vk_id)){
    echo  "";
    }
    else {
    $vk = "<li><a href=\"http://vk.com/$vk_id\" target=\"_blank\"><i><img src=\"/images/icon_stream/vk.png\"></i>Вконтакте</a></li>";

    }

        if (empty($steam_id)){
    echo  "";
    }
    else {
    $steam = "<li><a href=\"http://steamcommunity.com/id/$steam_id\" target=\"_blank\"><i><img src=\"/images/icon_stream/steam.png\"></i>Steam</a></li>";

    } 
        if (empty($facebook_id)){
    echo  "";
    }
    else {
    $facebook = "<li><a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/$facebook_id\" target=\"_blank\"><i><img src=\"/images/icon_stream/facebook.png\"></i>Facebook</a></li>";

    } 
        if (empty($twitter_id)){
    echo  "";
    }
    else {
    $twitter = "<li><a href=\"https://twitter.com/$twitter_id\" target=\"_blank\"><i><img src=\"/images/icon_stream/twitter.png\"></i>Twitter</a></li>";

    } 
        if (empty($youtube_id)){
    echo  "";
    }
    else {
    $youtube = "<li><a href=\"http://www.youtube.com/user/$youtube_id\" target=\"_blank\"><i><img src=\"/images/icon_stream/youtube.png\"></i>YouTube</a></li>";

    }

    if ($service == "twitch")
    {
        $player = "<object type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" height=\"399\" width=\"500\" id=\"live_embed_player_flash\" data=\"http://ru.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=$ident\" bgcolor=\"#000000\"><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\" /><param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\" /><param name=\"allowNetworking\" value=\"all\" /><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://ru.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf\" /><param name=\"flashvars\" value=\"hostname=ru.twitch.tv&channel=$ident&auto_play=true&start_volume=25\" /></object>";
        $chat = "<iframe frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" id=\"chat_embed\" src=\"http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=$ident&amp;popout_chat=true\" height=\"350\" width=\"300\"></iframe>";
    }
    echo ("<h3 id=\"stream_name\"><span><center>Стрим от $name</center></span></h3>");
    echo("<center><table style=\"width: 852px; morgin: 0 auto; \">
<tr>
<td style=\"width: 500px; height:40px; float: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;\"><center>

<div class=\"share42init\"></div> 
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/share42/share42.js\"></script>
</center></td>
<td style=\"width: 300px; height:40px; float: right; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;\"><center><a href=\"/dobavit-svoj-strim\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"myButton\">Добавить свой стрим на сайт</a></center></td>
</tr>
</table></center> ");
    echo("<div class=\"wrapper\"><div class=\"player\">$player</div>");
    echo("<div class=\"chat\">
 <div class=\"section\">
    <ul class=\"tabs\">
        <li class=\"current\">Steam</li>
        <li>Vkontakte</li> 
        <!-- <li>3 tabs</li>  -->
    </ul>
    <div class=\"box visible\">
        <p>$chat</p>
    </div>
    <div class=\"box\">
        <p><div id=\"vk_comments\"></div></p>
    </div>

 <!-- <div class=\"box\">
        <p>3 tabs</p>
    </div> -->
</div></div>");

    echo ("<div class=\"wrapper\"><p></p>");
    echo("<p><a href=\"/translyatsii?streamer=$ident\"><h4>Onlie stream by $name</h4></a></p><div class=\"desc_stream\"><p>$desc</p></p>$reclama</div>");
    echo("<div class=\"desc_info\"><h3>Контакты Стримера:</h3>

    <ul class=\"dropdown\">
        $vk
        $steam
        $faceBook
        $twitter
        $youtube 
    </ul>

</div></div>");
      }  
    } 
}

else
{   
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM streams_new');
    $count = mysql_result($result,0);
    if ($count == NULL) 
    {
        echo ("Стримы не найдены");
    }

    $counter = 0;
    echo ("<table align = \"center\"  border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\"><tr>");

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM streams_new WHERE (state = 'ONLINE' and game = 'Dota 2') ORDER BY OBS DESC, featured DESC";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    while  ($stream = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
    {
        $counter++;
        FullStreamLayout($stream, $counter);
        if ($counter % 4 == 0)
        {
            echo ("</tr><tr>");
        }
    }
    echo ("</tr></table>"); 
}

?>
```

Comment: Каких именно ресурсов? Процессора? Оперативы? Трафика?

Answer (score 1):

Много двойных кавычек и переменных в них, быстрее будет работать с одинарными кавычками и конкатенацией строк. Зачем-то лишний раз значение одних переменных присваивается другим, таким образом лишняя память расходуется. Это есть как при получении данных из базы, так и при формировании запроса, так и при выводе из функции. Так же зачем-то делаются запросы без WHERE, так же нельзя использовать конструкцию SELECT * FROM, лучше прописывать все нужные поля, запрос будет более читабельным и в случае большего количества полей, запрос отработает быстрее. Так же непосредственно нужно провести оптимизацию таблиц, хотя бы проверить соответствие типов данных полей их содержимому и сделать индексы.

Comment: Отформатируйте ваше сообщение, чтобы его было удобно читать. ЗЫ: вопросу больше года...